# Ошибка в параметризованом запросе INSERT

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
public void updateQuery(String query,String name,String sub,int test,int vidp,int zad,int maks_mark,float midle_time, float midle_mark){
        try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query); //ошибка
            preparedStatement.setString(1,name);
            preparedStatement.setString(2,sub);
            preparedStatement.setInt(3,test);
            preparedStatement.setInt(4,vidp);
            preparedStatement.setInt(5,zad);
            preparedStatement.setInt(6,maks_mark);
            preparedStatement.setFloat(7,midle_time);
            preparedStatement.setFloat(8,midle_mark);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



connection.updateQuery("INSERT INTO discipline(name,sub,test,vidp,zad,maks_mark,midle_time,midle_mark) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", dis, sub, test_z, vidp_z, zad_z, 0, 0, 0); //ошибка
```

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Покажите, что такое у Вас connection.

Comment: DBConnection connection = new DBConnection("localhost", "root", "root", "test_lessons");

Comment: NPE на какую строку в коде указывает? connection.updateQuery? или на какую-то в этом методе?

Comment: connection.updateQuery и preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

Comment: preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query); //ошибка - вот этот connection как определен?

Comment: DBConnection connection = new DBConnection("localhost", "root", "root", "test_lessons");

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74211/discussion-between---and-user221117).